# LINQ query to select best sellers

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

Could a smart guy help me write a LINQ query to get the best selling products, where I have these 2 tables/classes in the [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) model:

```
Orders (OrderedItems)
OrderedItem (Product, Qty)
```

eg. (this obviously doesn't work)

```
Orders.OrderByDescending(o => Sum(o.OrderedItems.Qty))
      .Select(o => o.OrderedItems.Product)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't really need the Orders table at all.  Assuming every ordered item has a corresponding order, you should be able to do this.

```
var query =
    (from item in OrderedItem
    group item.Qty by item.Product into g
    orderby g.Sum() descending
    select g.Key).Take(5); // get the top 5 orders
```

Comment: How would you get the Key and the summed quantity?

Comment: You would then select both the key and the sum. `...select new { g.Key, Sum = g.Sum() }`

Answer (score 3):

I think you're using [Sum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534734.aspx) incorrectly.  I think this is what you want

```
Orders.OrderByDescending(o => o.OrderedItems.Sum(oi => oi.Qty))
      .Select(o => o.OrderedItems.Product)
```

Comment: Actually my example was wrong... It needs to take into account that a product may have been ordered more than once.

Comment: Ahh - Jeff's answer is probably what you need then

Answer (score 3):

```
class Product {
            public int Id { get; set; }
        }
        class OrderedItem
        {
            public Product Product { get; set; }

            public int Qty { get; set; }
        }
```

And then:

```
        List<OrderedItem> orders = new List<OrderedItem>();
        var products = orders.GroupBy(p => p.Product.Id).OrderByDescending(pi => pi.Sum(pii => pii.Qty)).Select(p=>p.Key);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public IQueryable<Product> Bestsellers(int? count)
    {
        var query = (from item in db.OrderDetails
                     group item.Qty by item.Product into g
                     orderby g.Sum() descending
                     select g.Key).Take(count??20); // get the top 5 orders

        return query;
    }
```